# React native error on compilation on fresh project

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

I created a new project as

```
react-native init test
cd test
```

then I run

```
react-native run-ios
```

and what I get is the following error. 
I'm not doing anything else. 
What am I missing??

[image]

Comment: And you've tried the 3 steps listed, and they didn't resolve the issue?

Comment: yep, unfortunately

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the root cause, there was an hidden error log saying that something was already on port 8081 so the system could not load properly.
Just do

```
lsof -i :8081
```

and kill the processes you see to free the port.